# Refactoring link in Rails 3.2.12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

## Refactoring an ugly URL

I link from a job to a new job application, but the URL generated for the application feels kind of messy and I'm wondering if there's a way to clean it up.

Is there a way to go from this not so pretty URL?:

```
http://localhost:3000/applications/new?application%5Bjob_id%5D=1
```

To this cleaner one?:

```
http://localhost:3000/applications/new
```

Thanks in advance!

## The code:

#### Jobs controller:

```
def show
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
end
```

#### Job show:

```
<%= link_to "New Application", new_application_path(:application => { :job_id => @job.id }) %>
```

#### Application controller

```
def new
  @application = Application.new(params[:application])
end
```

#### New Application

```
<%= form_for @application do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :job_id, :value => @application.job_id %>

  <%= f.label :email %>:
  <%= f.text_field :email %>

  <br />

  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

<% end %>
```

## EDIT

(added rake routes and routes.rb)

#### Rake routes

```
    applications GET    /applications(.:format)          applications#index
                 POST   /applications(.:format)          applications#create
 new_application GET    /applications/new(.:format)      applications#new
edit_application GET    /applications/:id/edit(.:format) applications#edit
     application GET    /applications/:id(.:format)      applications#show
                 PUT    /applications/:id(.:format)      applications#update
                 DELETE /applications/:id(.:format)      applications#destroy
            jobs GET    /jobs(.:format)                  jobs#index
                 POST   /jobs(.:format)                  jobs#create
         new_job GET    /jobs/new(.:format)              jobs#new
        edit_job GET    /jobs/:id/edit(.:format)         jobs#edit
             job GET    /jobs/:id(.:format)              jobs#show
                 PUT    /jobs/:id(.:format)              jobs#update
                 DELETE /jobs/:id(.:format)              jobs#destroy
```

#### Routes.rb

```
resources :applications

resources :jobs
```

Comment: Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources In your case I would go with http://localhost:3000/applicatons/:job_id/application or http://localhost:3000/applicatons/:job_id/applications/new. Depending if it is has_one or has_many.

Comment: Please run `rake routes` and show us the output.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `nested routes` (I recommend to use nested routes). But there are many solution to solve problem. To avoid params in `URL` (i.e.) `http://localhost:3000/applications/new?application%5Bjob_id%5D=1` to `http://localhost:3000/applications/new`. You need to use `form` in your show page instead of `link`. You can do as follows:

```
  <%= form_tag url_for(new_application_path) do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "application['job_id']", @job_id %> 
    <%= submit_tag "New application" %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I agree that nested resources are the way to go.  Although I've learned something new; I didn't know what form_tag was for.  Pretty cool!